# How to express the MeijerG as Bessel function, which leads to the general solution of the below differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I wanted to find the general solution of the following ODE. The ODE is not a linear differential with constant coefficient. Its is the fourth order differential equation. I used `DSolve` function along with boundary conditions, but unable to solve. How to solve this. In the paper I am referring,  the general solution is given by Bessel functions and modified Bessel functions of second order. Following is the Mathematica code that I tried to obtain the general solution, But I am getting something which is called as `MeijerG`. How to convert this function to Bessel function?

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\left(1-\frac{a}{b}x\right)^4\frac{d^2Y(x)}{dx^2}\right)-\frac{\omega^2}{c b^2}\left(1-\frac{a}{b}x\right)^2 Y(x)
\end{align*}

```
    s1 = (1 - a/b*x)^4*D[Y[x], {x, 2}];
    a1 = D[s1, {x, 2}];
    a2 = ω^2/(c*b^2) (1 - a/b*x)^2*Y[x];
    e1 = Simplify[a1 - a2]
    FullSimplify[DSolve[e1 == 0, Y[x], x]](*General soluction*)
    FullSimplify[DSolve[{e1 == 0, Y[0] == 0, Y''[0] == 0, Y[1] == 0, Y''[1] ==0},Y[x], x]]
```

The Link of the journal paper is [here](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1077546314550699).

Comment: What exactly is your question? Find the analytic particular solution? Make _Mathematica_ express the general solution in the same way as in the paper? Is the particular solution given in that paper? Can you add the link for the paper?

Comment: I actually looking for the analytical solution of the differential equation. In the paper the have mentioned the analytical solution. I just wanted to reproduce the same results. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1077546314550699

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, the so-called analytic solution in the paper still involves a unsolved transcendental equation. (At the end of Section 2.1: "…the natural frequencies of free bending vibrations for the beam with variable cross section are obtained by solving numerically a transcendental equation derived by employing the boundary conditions at the beam-ends. ") So, I doubt if the solution can be expressed in an explicit way.

Comment: Yes your right, My interest is to get the general solution mentioned in the paper using Mathematica. If I can able to get the general solution, then I apply four boundary conditions on that, I will get four system of equations. If I take the determinant of the matrix containing these systems of equations,  I will get the transcendental equation. Later I will solve this numerically using NSolve in Mathematica. Is it possible to do in Mathematica. Because when I solved for general solution I am getting some weird results  showing  some thing like "MeijerG" I dont know what is this?

Comment: This is a special function. For more information you may check the document of it and the [corresponding wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function). So the question now boils down to "how to express the `MeijerG` as Bessel function?". BTW you should clarify your question by adding these information to the body of the question, not only in the comment.

Comment: I didnt  get  that BTW

Comment: I mean, though you've clarified your question with the comments above, the body of the question still remains unclear. You should edit the question to include these information. This will make your question more attractive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86280/discussion-between-acoustics-and-xzczd).

Answer (score 3):

We make obvious simplifications.

```
(*b=1/d^2*Sqrt[(Iyy*Y)/(ρ*A)];k1=α/d;k2=ω^2/(b*d^4)*)
(*-1+k1*x->x;k=k2*k1^4;*)
a = x^4*D[W[x], {x, 2}];
a1 = D[a, {x, 2}];

a2 = k*x^2*W[x];
e1 = Simplify[a1 - a2]
(*x^2 (-k W[x] + 12 W'[x] + x (8 W'''[x] + x W''''[x]))*)
```

Then the basic equation has the form.

```
eq=-k W[x] + 12 W'[x] + x (8 W'''[x] + x W''''[x]);
```

General solution of the equation

```
DSolve[eq == 0, W[x], x]

(*{{W[x] -> -((
     3 I (BesselI[2, 2 k^(1/4) Sqrt[x]] - 
        BesselJ[2, 2 k^(1/4) Sqrt[x]]) C[1])/(
     4 Sqrt[k]
       x)) - ((BesselI[2, 2 k^(1/4) Sqrt[x]] + 
       BesselJ[2, 2 k^(1/4) Sqrt[x]]) C[3])/(Sqrt[k] x) + 
    C[4] MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-1, 0}, {-(1/2), 1/2}}, (k x^2)/16] + 
    C[2] MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-(1/2), 1/2}, {-1, 0}}, (k x^2)/16]}}*)
```

To find a solution to an equation with boundary conditions, you can use General solution and `Solve[]`. Do not use `FullSimplify[]`.